# Android Context: Type mismatch for 'this'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I am creating a Notification class, with a method that initializes a Notification Builder. The first parameter of `NotificationCompat.Builder` is a `Context` variable. I provide `this` for the parameter, but I get the following error:

> Type mismatch: Required: Context Found: Notification

The error happens at the first line in the code for my function `setNotificationAtTime`

Below is my code:

```
package com.example.notificationapp

import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import android.content.Context
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import java.security.AccessController.getContext
import java.util.*

class Notification(title:String, description:String, date: Date) {
    // Attributes
    private var description:String = ""

    // Initialization
    init {
        // Download the constructor parameters into the object's variables
        this.description = description
    }

    // Getters
    fun getDescription():String {
        return description
    }

    // Setters
    fun setDescription(newDescription:String) {
        this.description = newDescription;
    }

    // Method to set the notification at a specific time
    fun setNotificationAtTime(time:Date) {
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
            "com.example.notificationapp")
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` refers to `Notification` when you call `NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "com.example.notificationapp")` since you it's called inside `Notification` class. But you need an instance of `Context` in this case

Answer (score 0):

Read [**NotificationCompat.Builder**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder)

```
NotificationCompat.Builder (Context context, 
                String channelId)
```

You should collect **`Context`** Object at first

```
class Notification(context:Context,title:String, description:String, date: Date)
```

Then pass the **`Context`** object below

```
 fun setNotificationAtTime(time:Date) {
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "com.example.notificationapp").apply {

    }
  }
```